# disabling character escaping in Flask's url_for function

Tags: url, routes, flask, escaping

Does Flask's `url_for` method have an option to disable autoescaping?  So if I have an endpoint called `getUser` with a route like this: `/user/<userID>`, I want to call `url_for('getUser', userID='%')` and have it return `/user/%`.  Currently it will escape the % symobl and give out `/user/%25`.  I want to do that because `url_for` has to run at template compile-time, but the final URL is composed when a javscript script runs.  I will be using a javascript string substitution method to convert `/user/%` into `/user/abcd`, but the substitution script I'm using requires you to use a `%` symbol as the placeholder.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`url_for` does not support your use case, but assuming you are using it inside a Jinja template you could just add a call to [`replace`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#replace) to remove the encoding:

```
{{ url_for('get_user', user_id='%') | replace('%25', '%') }}
```

Alternatively, if you passing the URL around in normal Python code you could use [`urllib.parse.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote) (or [`urllib.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote) if you are still on Python 2):

```
url = url_for('get_user', 'user_id'='%')
url = unquote(url)
```

Comment: Tip: you don't need the replace trick just to add query paremeters to an url. E.g.: url_for('search', q='some text').

Comment: My passed in `_anchor` to `url_for` was being encoded. `unquote` solved the issue for me. Thanks!