# How to display @ instead of being encoded as %40 (urlencode) in browser address bar?

Tags: python, html, url, flask

I've tried to use this line in Python3 (Flask) project, which is UTF-8 encoding:

```
@app.route('/@<username>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

But in browser address bar, it always displays like:

```
http://example.com/%40username
```

How to display the original '@' in browser address bar? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you are using url_for from python code? One approach in such case is to call urllib.unquote on return value of url_for

Sample code:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, redirect
import urllib
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return redirect(urllib.unquote(url_for('user', username='test')))

@app.route('/@<username>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def user(username):
    return "Hello %s" % (username)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Disabling character escaping is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27300332/disabling-character-escaping-in-flasks-url-for-function)

Comment: PS, when I type 'example.com/@username' into the browser address bar, the @ display as normal @. I've tried your example code, it works too for typing by hand. My problem is when this route rendered from template file, eg. href="{{ url_for('.user', username=username) }}, it displays @ as %40 on the new page's address bar.

Comment: is this link useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27300332/disabling-character-escaping-in-flasks-url-for-function

Comment: Thanks Kevin, the link your recommended gives me help!